# Partitioning during Ubuntu installation

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, system-installation

I have 3 Drives in my system. 2 HDD and 1 SSD. and I want to install ubuntu in the SSD. if I chose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" will it erase my other drives or I will have a choice of selecting my drive?

[image]

Comment: With multiple drives, I would never let any of the auto choices be used. Only use Something Else. I prefer to partition in advance, but you can partition during install. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions use swap file so swap partition optional:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu  & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Comment: @oldfred so, should i unplug the other 2 drives before installing?? would that cause a problem?

Comment: Unplugging is a great way to go. Your data will be safe. If Windows is on one of the other drives and you want to dual boot you will need to update grub once everything is reconnected